# Can't acess internet

Tags: 8.0

.My new page plus Lumia 822 won't let me access the internet,it keeps telling me to disable airplane mode. The phone shows it being off, this phone is new.The phone has stock 8.0 operating system.

Comment: Have you tried toggling airplane mode on and off? What about restarting the phone? Are you trying to use WiFi or mobile data? Are you connected to a network in either case? Does the problem occur in all apps? When did it start?

Answer (score 1):

Just perform a soft reset if even restarting is not working for you.

For performing a soft reset Press and hold <kbd>power</kbd>+<kbd>vol down</kbd> for about 10 seconds until the phone vibrates.